# How to test with dbunit using Composite

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

I try test with dbunit using composite something [like this exeample](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/master/Samples/BankAccountDB/BankAccountCompositeTest.php) but I have the error said that `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultConnection not found`.
even including the `require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php'` I have this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samples contain a typo.

Here's the fix

```
diff --git a/Samples/BankAccountDB/BankAccountCompositeTest.php b/Samples/BankAccountDB/BankAccountCompositeTest.php
index 3dc0035..d314c39 100644
--- a/Samples/BankAccountDB/BankAccountCompositeTest.php
+++ b/Samples/BankAccountDB/BankAccountCompositeTest.php
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@ public function setUp()
      */
     protected function getDatabaseTester()
     {
-        $connection = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite');
+        $connection = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite');
         $tester = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DefaultTester($connection);
         $tester->setSetUpOperation(PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::CLEAN_INSERT());
         $tester->setTearDownOperation(PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::NONE());
```